# Processing: apply core patch and compile

Tags: macos, processing, patch, javac

I want to apply this patch

https://github.com/processing/processing/pull/5881

into my own processing core for use in my PDE. How do I go about ?

i can take the source here

https://github.com/processing/processing

apply the patch
compile that (eg using javac) to get a core.jar

But in the App, there are two core.jars :

`Processing.app/Contents/Java/core/library/core.jar`
and
`Processing.app/Contents/Java/core.jar`

which one is what ?

Answer (score 2):

Did this:

**read this howto**

https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/build/howto.txt

**clone this repo**

https://github.com/processing/processing

**downloaded the correct version java**

get an account at oracle.com
and download java (in my case 8u202) here

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-java-archive-javase8-downloads.html

and install that.

**build the app with ant**

Go into your cloned repo and

```
cd build
ant run
```

This builds a processing PDE in the build/ directory of your repo
and opens it. It works.

**apply the patch and build it again**

```
git checkout -b pull/5881
git pull origin pull/5881/head
ant run
```

That creates a new branch, pulls the patch I wanted to apply, applies that, builds the PDE again and runs it.

And the patch fixed my problem :-)